# Wall Mounted Light Fixture Mounting Plate

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

I'm prepping for drywall and will need to install a wall-mounted fixture, but the bolts that go through the mounting plate to attach the fixture are lined up with where the plate attaches to the box.  Since this is wall mounted, those bolts need to be horizontal so that the fixture is straight on the wall.

It has been suggested that I can get a different mounting bar (not sure what it would look like) but I don't understand how that would make a difference since the fixture bolts going through the plate would likely still hit the section where the plate attaches to the box.

It seems as though the holes in the box need to be in a different location (anywhere besides where they are now).

Thanks

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to adjust the screws so they protrude from the front of the bracket just enough to secure the fixture to the wall with the included cap nuts. Then cut off the part with the screw heads, flush with the back of the bracket. Good luck.

Many wire cutters/strippers have the ability to cut this size bolt and protect the threads.

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks for the suggestion.  That would definitely work.  That got me thinking - the holes that the fixture uses on the plate line up with a set of holes on the box so I can probably just snip the heads (or buy bolts with no heads) and screw right through the plate into the box and still adjust the bolts accordingly for the fixture.

Comment: @Chris That will work but be careful screwing the screws into the box after snipping off the heads. If you damage the threads you won't be able to screw the cap nuts on... been there, done that in my much younger years.